# Why is Nodejs throwing an error named: TypeError: user.comparePassword is not a function?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am making login where I have to compare password from user input with stored password in database. I have written the comparePassword function in my model. But I can not acccess this from the router where I have written the the login route, as I am getting this error: `TypeError: user.comparePassword is not a function`.

**Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const saltRounds = 10;

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minlenght: 5,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    role: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    token: {
        type: String
    },
    tokenExp: {
        type: Number
    }

});
userSchema.pre('save', function (next){
    var user = this;
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    }else{
        next();
    }
})

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(plainPassword, cb){
    bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, this.password, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch)
    });
}

userSchema.methods.generateToken = function(cb){
    var user = this;
    var token = jwt.sign({
        data: user._id.toHexString()
      }, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 });
    user.token = token;

    user.save(function(err, user){
        if(err) return (cb(err));
        cb(null, user);
    })
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**Router**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/User');

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { email,password } = req.body;
        const user = new userModel(req.body);
        existingUser = await userModel.findOne({ email: email });
        if (existingUser) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "email already exists" });
        } else {
            await user.save();
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, user: user })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }

});

//login
router.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
    //match email
    const user = userModel.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(!user) return res.json({success : false, message:"No user found with that email"});

    console.log(user.comparePassword());
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) =>{
        if (!isMatch){
            return res.json({loginSuccess: false, message: "wrong password"})
        }
    })

    user.generateToken((err, user)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(400).json({error: err});
        res.cookie("x-auth", user.token).status(200).json({
            message:"Login Success"
        })
    })
})



module.exports = router;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async/await here while logging in,

```
router.post('/login', (req, res)=>{
   const user = userModel.findOne({email: req.body.email})
```

The above statement returns promise, so you are getting error that **user.comparePassword** is not a function.
Update above line with

```
//login
router.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    //match email
    const user = await userModel.findOne({email: req.body.email});
```

Comment: Now I am getting another error, called cb is not a function in comparePassword. Can You please help me with this?

Comment: You can use async/await with model methods also, ```// Compare password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (candidatePassword) {
  const comparison = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password)
  return comparison
}
```
And match statement as ```const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(req.body.password)```

Comment: Please refer bcryp promises on https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: I have done as you told but getting this error: if(err) return cb(err): cb is not a function.

Comment: Remove this line from code ```console.log(user.comparePassword());```